# Angular JS textbox validation allow particular text restrict other values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to restrict the user to type other than "open" or "closed" string values.

that means user can only type "open" or "closed" text and also maxlength is 6. created the directive for that, but  still it is allowing other text values, how to capture or allow user to type only those two text values.

plunkr link

http://plnkr.co/edit/LFbPbRAMyYZGhTZ1F7GU?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


});

app.directive('wmBlock', function ($parse) {
    return {

        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

          elm.bind('keypress', function(e){

            if(scope.foo==="open" || scoe.foo==="closed"){
              return true;
            }
            else
            {
               e.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }
            }
          });
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: good try but when u have simple requirement of two known options.......why don't you try with a drop down

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/2422/

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary that is valid question. but client requirement is like that only

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('wmBlock', function ($browser, $parse) {
   return {

    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      $element.bind('keypress', function(e){

        $browser.defer(
          function(){

            var modelGetter = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);

            var value = modelGetter($scope);
            var expression = new RegExp(/^(open|close)$/);
            if(expression.test(value))
               alert("founded!");

          });


      });
    }
  }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using $watch function

```
app.directive('isNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope) {    
            scope.$watch('opennumber', function(newValue,oldValue) {
            if(newValue=="o" || newValue=="c") return;
            if(newValue=="op" || newValue=="ope" || newValue=="open") return;
            if(newValue=="cl" || newValue=="clo" || newValue=="clos" ||  newValue=="close" || newValue=="closed") return;

                if (newValue) {
                    scope.opennumber = oldValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/2422/